# How can i prevent from moving the camera view under the terrain?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using this mouseorbit script attached to a camera.
The problem is when i move the camera with the mouse and rotating it so the camera is under the terrain.
I want that when it get to the terrain height then stop don't move down i mean don't get to this view under the character maximum to be in the terrain height..

[image: Mouse Orbit]

To stop on terrain height i mean something like that when it's getting to this:

[image: Mouse Orbit 001]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MouseOrbit : MonoBehaviour
{
    /* These variables are what tell the camera how its going to function by
      * setting the viewing target, collision layers, and other properties
      * such as distance and viewing angles */
    public Transform viewTarget;
    public LayerMask collisionLayers;
    public float distance = 6.0f;
    public float distanceSpeed = 150.0f;
    public float collisionOffset = 0.3f;
    public float minDistance = 4.0f;
    public float maxDistance = 12.0f;
    public float height = 1.5f;
    public float horizontalRotationSpeed = 250.0f;
    public float verticalRotationSpeed = 150.0f;
    public float rotationDampening = 0.75f;
    public float minVerticalAngle = -60.0f;
    public float maxVerticalAngle = 60.0f;
    public bool useRMBToAim = false;

    /* These variables are meant to store values given by the script and
     * not the user */
    private float h, v, smoothDistance;
    private Vector3 newPosition;
    private Quaternion newRotation, smoothRotation;
    private Transform cameraTransform;

    /* This is where we initialize our script */
    void Start()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    /* This is where we set our private variables, check for null errors,
     * and anything else that needs to be called once during startup */
    void Initialize()
    {
        h = this.transform.eulerAngles.x;
        v = this.transform.eulerAngles.y;

        cameraTransform = this.transform;
        smoothDistance = distance;

        NullErrorCheck();
    }

    /* We check for null errors or warnings and notify the user to fix them */
    void NullErrorCheck()
    {
        if (!viewTarget)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Please make sure to assign a view target!");
            Debug.Break();
        }
        if (collisionLayers == 0)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("Make sure to set the collision layers to the layers the camera should collide with!");
        }
    }

    /* This is where we do all our camera updates. This is where the camera
     * gets all of its functionality. From setting the position and rotation,
     * to adjusting the camera to avoid geometry clipping */
    void LateUpdate()
    {
        if (!viewTarget)
            return;

        /* We check for right mouse button functionality, set the rotation
         * angles, and lock the mouse cursor */
        if (!useRMBToAim)
        {
            /* Check to make sure the game isn't paused and lock the mouse cursor*/
            if (Time.timeScale > 0.0f)
                Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;

            h += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * horizontalRotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
            v -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * verticalRotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

            h = ClampAngle(h, -360.0f, 360.0f);
            v = ClampAngle(v, minVerticalAngle, maxVerticalAngle);

            newRotation = Quaternion.Euler(v, h, 0.0f);
        }
        else
        {
            if (Input.GetMouseButton(1))
            {
                /* Check to make sure the game isn't paused and lock the mouse cursor */
                if (Time.timeScale > 0.0f)
                    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;

                h += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * horizontalRotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
                v -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * verticalRotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

                h = ClampAngle(h, -360.0f, 360.0f);
                v = ClampAngle(v, minVerticalAngle, maxVerticalAngle);

                newRotation = Quaternion.Euler(v, h, 0.0f);
            }
            else
            {
                Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Confined;
            }
        }

        /* We set the distance by moving the mouse wheel and use a custom
         * growth function as the time value for linear interpolation */
        distance = Mathf.Clamp(distance - Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") * 10, minDistance, maxDistance);
        smoothDistance = Mathf.Lerp(smoothDistance, distance, TimeSignature(distanceSpeed));

        /*We give the rotation some smoothing for a nicer effect */
        smoothRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(smoothRotation, newRotation, TimeSignature((1 / rotationDampening) * 100.0f));

        newPosition = viewTarget.position;
        newPosition += smoothRotation * new Vector3(0.0f, height, -smoothDistance);

        /* Calls the function to adjust the camera position to avoid clipping */
        CheckSphere();

        smoothRotation.eulerAngles = new Vector3(smoothRotation.eulerAngles.x, smoothRotation.eulerAngles.y, 0.0f);

        cameraTransform.position = newPosition;
        cameraTransform.rotation = smoothRotation;
    }

    /* This is where the camera checks for a collsion hit within a specified radius,
     * and then moves the camera above the location it hit with an offset value */
    void CheckSphere()
    {
        /* Add height to our spherecast origin */
        Vector3 tmpVect = viewTarget.position;
        tmpVect.y += height;

        RaycastHit hit;

        /* Get the direction from the camera position to the origin */
        Vector3 dir = (newPosition - tmpVect).normalized;

        /* Check a radius for collision hits and then set the new position for
         * the camera */
        if (Physics.SphereCast(tmpVect, 0.3f, dir, out hit, distance, collisionLayers))
        {
            newPosition = hit.point + (hit.normal * collisionOffset);
        }
    }

    /* Keeps the angles values within their specificed minimum and maximum
     * inputs while at the same time putting the values back to 0 if they
     * go outside of the 360 degree range */
    private float ClampAngle(float angle, float min, float max)
    {
        if (angle < -360)
            angle += 360;

        if (angle > 360)
            angle -= 360;

        return Mathf.Clamp(angle, min, max);
    }

    /* This is our custom logistic growth time signature with speed as input */
    private float TimeSignature(float speed)
    {
        return 1.0f / (1.0f + 80.0f * Mathf.Exp(-speed * 0.02f));
    }
}
```

It looks like the script i grabbed already handles terrain collision... i just need to make sure to set the collision layers on it to include the terrain. But not sure how to do it.

What i tried:

I added now a new layer in the inspector called it Terrain.
Then in the hierarchy on the Terrain i change it's layer to terrain.
Also in the script i selected Terrain. But it's still not working.

In the screenshot the top is the inspector of the camera with the script selected in Collision Layers Terrain.
In the bottom the terrain inspector selected Terrain as :Layer

[image: Tried]

Comment: I tried the script in a test project. It worked nicely with the settings you've set. Is there any chance that you have used the same script on multiple cameras in your scene? Or may be you have turned off collision between default layer and terrain layer from **Edit->Project Settings->Physics**?

Comment: @ZayedUpal my camera is a child of a empty GameObject and the script is attached to the GameObject not the camera. Both the GameObject and child camera don't have any colliders. The terrain have it's own collider Terrain Collider.  So i have to attach the script directly to the camera or it's fine attaching it to the parent GameObject ? You can see in the bottom screenshot in my question the FollowCamera gameobject and the camera is child of it. And do i need to add any collider/s to the empty GameObject or the Camera ? Maybe i need to add to the GameObject or the camera Rigidbody ?

Comment: @ZayedUpal Can you show maybe a screenshot of the hierarchy of the camera and the inspector what did you do ?

Comment: Generally, you would add the script directly to the camera. However, putting it to it's parent will also work, if camera's local position,rotation is set to zero and scale to 1. Here's a screenshot of my test: http://imgur.com/a/nti61

Comment: @ZayedUpal Great working. Thank you.

Comment: Your example of using the sphere cast helped me - I had this same problem but when a ray/linecast wasn't cutting it (allowed camera to clip terrain), I tried the spherecast with some tweaks for my code, and it works very well. Thanks!

Comment: @ZayedUpal Please consider posting this as an answer for future viewers

Answer (score 1):

Many answers to this question.
But here's my take on it since I am fairly certain this solution is interesting compared to all solutions you will find online related to unity 3rd person controllers.

---

**Abstract**
In Unity, you could take the usual approach of having an empty object and having that be the parent of the camera, etc... But what people in the industry would typically do is use a mathematical formula called [**Spherical coordinates**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system).
This, by far, is the best approach for 3rd person controllers from my experience and its the most elegant and beautiful approach. All you need to do after implementing this approach, is shoot a ray from the camera down a meter, and if it detects anything, then change a single value in your spherical coordinates formula which would make the sphere around the player smaller which gives the effect of collision

**Implementation**
Here's a snippet of code which shows a single function needed to create the spherical coordinates formula.

```
private Vector3 sphericalCoordinates()
{
    float m = distanceFromPlayer;
    v = mouseY;
    h = mouseX;

    x = m * Mathf.Sin(v) * Mathf.Cos(h);
    z = m * Mathf.Sin(v) * Mathf.Sin(h);
    y = m * Mathf.Cos(v);

    Vector3 pos = new Vector3(x, y, z);
    return pos;
}
```

m = magnitude.
You can think of this as the radius from the sphere, this is what you change to give the collision effect.

I later use this snippet to bind the player with the camera in trigger.
[NOTE: very unclean code, I just wanted to show you a basic concept, definitely make it cleaner later]

```
Vector3 getCamRotWORLD()
{
    Vector3 camRotWORLD = new Vector3(0, transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y, 0);
    return camRotWORLD;
}

void adjustPlayerRot()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        player.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(player.transform.rotation.x, getCamRotWORLD().y, player.transform.rotation.z);
        player.transform.Translate(0, 0, playerScript.speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
    {
        player.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(player.transform.rotation.x, getCamRotWORLD().y - 90, player.transform.rotation.z);
        player.transform.Translate(0, 0, playerScript.speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
    {
        player.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(player.transform.rotation.x, getCamRotWORLD().y - 180, player.transform.rotation.z);
        player.transform.Translate(0, 0, playerScript.speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
    {
        player.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(player.transform.rotation.x, getCamRotWORLD().y + 90, player.transform.rotation.z);
        player.transform.Translate(0, 0, playerScript.speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Here's how my update looks like in case you really would like to snatch the implementation instead of trying to experiment with it yourself.

```
private void Update()
{
    mouseX -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * (sensitivity * Time.deltaTime);
    mouseY -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * (sensitivity * Time.deltaTime);

    playerCam.transform.LookAt(player.transform);
    playerCam.transform.position = new Vector3(
        sphericalCoordinates().x + player.transform.position.x,
        sphericalCoordinates().y,
        sphericalCoordinates().z + player.transform.position.z
        );
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the community. This is a thoughtful answer. Also, this actually appears to be the _first_ answer on this question! The other suggestion was posted as a comment. (Acknowledging that distinction may be a bit subtle to a new contributor such as yourself; answers are given special treatment on Stack Overflow.)